# How to pass a variable from CMake to conanfile.py

Tags: cmake, conan

I want to pass a variable/value from a CMake file to conanfile.py. The CMake file will be called during build method in conanfile.py and I would like to access this variable/value in package method of conanfile.py. How can I do that?

Comment: CMake CACHE variable are saved in `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory. So, if you know that the variable you want to retrieve is the CACHE'd one, you could parse content of `CMakeCache.txt` (you will find the format of that file to be quite simple). Alternatively, you may modify your CMake project so it will create a file with a variable's value. So after `cmake` completes, your `conanfile.py` could open that file and read the value from it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for the comment. If parsing the content of a file is the only option, then I will directly parse the CMake file itself which sets the value/variable. Thanks oncea again for this idea!

Comment: Yes, the ``package()`` method has access to the source and build folders, the easiest seems to just parse the file there.